# Python: How to predict and group texts based on their entity?

Tags: python, nlp

Given some records of texts such as below, how do you organize the texts into their entity definition? For example, automatically know which are addresses, emails, and phone numbers, and names and group them, even though the occurence of such text are not uniform and it's not always guaranteed that they will be present. This is a tough problem because there's no tag elements to segregate them, it's just raw text only separated by newline and the dashes to separate the results. I am wondering how I can go about approaching this problem, what techniques are needed to accomplish this.

```
James W.
342 Ave.
Seattle, WA
483948
483-428-1311
james@w.edu

-------------


Cecil F.
100 Ave.
San Fransico, CA
cecil@mail.com

--------------


Steve Frein
(+12) 142-2221
158 Saint St.,
Berlin, Germany
```

Comment: Probably looking into regexes for each of the entities would be a way to go about it.

Comment: @shaktimaan I thought that too but it won't work for cases where the string is totally reliant on the entity definition. for example, product category, it could be anything, but only humans would be able to notice this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a long road ahead of you. First, go through you're dataset looking for recognizable patterns for each line time and write a unique regex to match them. Run your file through your collection of regex's and emit any line that does NOT match. Overtime, you'll eventually nail down the exceptions.

Comment: I'm shying away from regexes because it won't work for cases where the simple pattern is not enough. For example, the occupation of a person can be anything, it'd be very tough to do it with just regex unless you knew ahead of time every single possible permutations.

Comment: If there is no predictable pattern -- the project is no go.